# How can form validation be simplified using jQuery and Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to create a validation form using jQuery and Codeigniter.
This code is actually running well. But what I want is to make this code shorter and simpler.

```
<?php if (validation_errors()==true) {?>
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php if (form_error('nama')) { ?>
  $('#nama').addClass('isInValid');
  $('#nama').on('keyup',function(){
  $('#nama').removeClass('isInValid');
  });
<?php } ?>
<?php if (form_error('email')) { ?>
  $('#email').addClass('isInValid');
  $('#email').on('keyup',function(){
  $('#email').removeClass('isInValid');
  });
<?php } ?>
<?php if (form_error('message')) { ?>
  $('#message').addClass('isInValid');
  $('#message').on('keyup',function(){
  $('#message').removeClass('isInValid');
  });
<?php } ?>

</script>

<?php } ?>
```

This is my controller code:

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Name','htmlspecialchars|trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','htmlspecialchars|trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message','Message','htmlspecialchars|trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[400]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()===true) {
      $nama =$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('nama'));
      $email = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email'));
      $message = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('message'));
      $this->Contact_m->sendMessage($nama,$email,$message);
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Thanks for contact us'.$nama);
      redirect('Halaman/contact');
    }
```

Comment: use class instead of id may help you to short your script

Comment: You can use form_validation config file to store your rules at. So your code is shorter in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery you can add removeClass, addClass and keyup event in a js function and simply class that function when needed instead of repeating the code

```
<?php if (validation_errors()==true) {?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function errorClass(id) {
  $(id).addClass('isInValid');
  $(id).on('keyup',function(){
  $(id).removeClass('isInValid');
  });
}
<?php if (form_error('nama')) { ?>
  errorClass('#nama');
<?php } ?>
<?php if (form_error('email')) { ?>
  errorClass('#email');
<?php } ?>
<?php if (form_error('message')) { ?>
  errorClass('#message');
<?php } ?>



</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: its still need to created new id like this right? $('#email').addClass('isInValid');
  $('#email').on('keyup',function(){
  $('#email').removeClass('isInValid');

Comment: @FarisDewantoro pass id as parameter. Answer updated.